# How to enable and disable upgradeInsecureRequests csp directive using Helmet 4.4.1 version node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-security-policy, helmet.js, upgrade-insecure-requests

I have tried this using Helmet 4.4.1 version both of them below sets to true for upgrade-insecure-requests CSP

```
upgradeInsecureRequests: [] and upgradeInsecureRequests: ['true']
```

Which of the above format is correct to use?

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
app.use(
        helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
            directives: {
                "script-src": ["'self'"],
                upgradeInsecureRequests: null
            },
        })
    );
```

Setting **upgradeInsecureRequests** to null:

```
upgradeInsecureRequests: null
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
defaultDirectives = helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives();
delete defaultDirectives['upgrade-insecure-requests'];

app.use( helmet() );
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  directives: {
    ...defaultDirectives,
  },
}));
```

The `delete` part removes the `upgrade-insecure-requests` key in the `defaultDirectives` object.

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of trial and errors, I've got it working.
I did it like this:

```js
const defaultCspOptions = helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives();
delete defaultCspOptions["upgrade-insecure-requests"]

app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    useDefaults: false,
    directives: { ...defaultCspOptions },
  })
)
```

Almost like Nico Serrano's answer, yes. In fact it inspired this. I just add `useDefaults: false`. Otherwise, even though the `'upgrade-insecure-requests'` property is no longer exists in the `defaultCspOptions`, the helmet automatically reappend any missing property with the default value. Rendering the `delete` part useless.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: we can simply add upgradeInsecureRequests: []

Comment: This sets it to `true`, but how can I set it to `false`?

Comment: In that case just don't provide this prop i.e upgradeInsecureRequests

Comment: the problem is now that the browser set `upgrade-insecure-requests` by default - but internally i need to mix http inside https and i trust the server because it's mine - so, how to disable it ?